# My kitten Melody just doesn't know how to be a cat!

Tags: cats, behavior

At the beginning of this year, a kitten was washed up in Cyclone Gabrielles floods, which we adopted and named Melody. She must have been around 3-4 weeks old, much too young to be away from the mother. Since then, she doesn't really know how to "cat" lets say. She does act like one, but at times she doesn't, just extremely antisocial and fighting non stop. We have two other cats, both boys, and much older than she is. Does anyone know anything about this?

EDIT from comments: Melody was neutured around june, the boys were neutered years ago, over 7 to just guess. Fred and Charlie have lived with Melody since she was rescued. Melody isn't ill, shes been with the boys for almost 10 months, she definetly has confidence, and she doesn't get attention from the boys, she forces attention pretty much. Hope this helps at all?

**I guess the question would be how to react when she constantly fights the boys.** Charlie can recognize that it is play fighting sometimes, and plays along, but I don't think Fred grew up with a kitten (he came from next door, where they had a dog)

Comment: Please give more information. Are the cats neutered/spayed (at which age)? Did they live together since the rescue of Melody? And what is your question? As more precise you can phrase your question or aim, as more helpful the answers will be for you.

Comment: Without knowing what you think "being a cat" is, we can't say whether the answer is that she's young, she's new to the clowder and lacks confidence, she's getting unwanted attention from the boys, she's just not very social, she's ill... Specifics please; we can't answer an unasked question.

Comment: Melody was neutured around june, the boys were neutered years ago, over 7 to just guess. Fred and Charlie have lived with Melody since she was rescued. Melody isn't ill, shes been with the boys for almost 10 months, she definetly has confidence, and she doesn't get attention from the boys, she forces attention pretty much. Hope this helps at all?

Comment: What is your question? "know anything about" is to broad for this site. Focus onto one question or one aim you want to reach (i.e. how can I train, how should I react to x or y, aim is they live along in peace...)

Comment: I guess the question would be how to react when she constantly fights the boys. Charlie can recognize that it is play fighting sometimes, and plays along, but I don't think Fred grew up with a kitten (he came from next door, where they had a dog)

Comment: If no damage is being done and no fur pulled out, it's wrestling rather than serious fighting. I might separate them for a while (see past answers about how to introduce a new cat in a way that minimizes actual fighting). They may be friends, they may just tolerate each other, one may be the Annoying Sibling, or someone may decide they really want the other gone. You can try to influence that and set behavioral standards and keep them from being too jealous of each other's share of your time, but in the end they're going to have to negotiate how they want to interact with each other.